# weblogic work manager HARVESTER_WM max thread constrint in 12 c

Tags: weblogic12c

We are keep getting work manager thread limit error in weblogic server log. Though our app is working fine, i would like to know what is the issue here and what kind of impact it can have in future to our app. Since this just the POC we are kind of ignoring it

java.lang.RuntimeException: MaxThreads constraint 'HARVESTER_WM' queue for workManager 'HARVESTER_WM' exceeded maximum capacity of '8000' elements. Max threads constraint count is set to 1